# What to say to comfort someone if he thinks he had made something bad?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, sentence-meaning

Say, someone unintentionally has broken something owned by someone else. But this something was not important to the owner. In German, to comfort the person, the owner would say:

> Das ist nicht schlimm.

Google Translator translates it to:

> That's not bad.

But I'm not sure, if this translation is a really idiomatic sentence in English to express this meaning.
Is it?

Comment: The idiomatic form is *It's not **so** bad*. Without the "intensifier" ***so***, the implication would be that the situation isn't ***at all*** bad, which usually wouldn't be what you meant (that although the situation is *somewhat* bad, it's not bad enough to justify your friend being really upset about it).

Answer (score 1):

More likely responses are:

> It's not serious
>   It doesn't matter
>   It's of no importance
>   Don't worry about it
>   It's easily fixed/mended